# How can I perform a jquery action when link is clicked from another page?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, expander

I'm creating an e-newsletter with jquery expander boxes for each article. By default, each expander box is closed. We send out an email teaser ahead of each issue with links to each article. I'm wondering if there is any way to expand the article to which I link in the code of the teaser (or possibly within the class of the named link). For reference, the jquery file can be found here: http://jjnursingnotes.com/NOV12/jquery.expander.js

The HTML for the newsletter is as follows. Content within the div layer "expander" is what I want displayed when a link to http://jjnursingnotes.com/NOV12#01 is inserted into the email teaser.

```
<div class="expander">
    <a name="01"></a>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <h3>content</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, just find that anchor tag with the given name (pulled from `window.location.hash`), traverse to it's parent, and expand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the specifics of your expander plugin, here's a solution I used recently in one of my own sites. Hopefully you can customize to work with the expander plugin you're using. I cannot take the credit for variable parsing, this originated elsewhere.

Your link would need to be setup as such:

```
http://jjnursingnotes.com/NOV12?section=01
```

Then your JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Redirect to Appropriate Section
var urlParams = {};
(function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

    while (match = search.exec(query))
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();

$(document).ready( function(){
    if ( urlParams['section'] != '' ) {
        // urlParams['section'] variable = the ?section=XXX part of URL
        // Here is where you would need integration with expanding box

        // Assuming you use something like <div class="expander" id="sect01">
        // as your expander, something to this effect ought to work:

        $("#sect" + urlParams['section'] ).find(".read-more a").click();

        // Position document at start of anchor 
        $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $("#sect" + urlParams['section'] ).offset().top }, 500 );
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's Karl Swedberg's expander plugin ;)

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find the documentation for the plugin

Comment: Thanks for the help, worked like a charm. Only question now is relating to the link. How can I also link to <a name="01">? I'd assume adding #01 either after section=01 or NOV12 would work, but it's not happening.

Comment: Updated code, if I understood what you meant, it should work :)

Comment: I have now changed expander plugin for Karl Swedberg's 'summarize' plugin. I'm looking through and can't figure out how this should affect the links, but for some reason now the links are no longer working. Any reason for this? Updated file is http://jjnursingnotes.com/DEC12